# Sending email from python script to s

Tags: python

I have written a python script that attaches a text file and mail it to some email ids.

The attached file is base 64 encoded.

I should decode the text before i send mails..

What must i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`base64`](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) module:

```
import base64

decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
```

Comment: hi.. i use the above decode code.. but i get the following error.."a2b_base64() argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not None" .. what has to  be done?